# $(this) is not saving in local storage....basically wanna addclass to $(this) and want it there after reload

Tags: jquery, local-storage, this, addclass

```
$("ul").on("click" , "li.afterdone" , function(event){

    $(this).toggleClass("done")

});
```

This is my code:

I want 'done' to stay on that perticular `li.afterdone` when page reload
I tried cookie and local storage but I think I'm not getting the core of it

This is what I want:

I want to add "done" to `$(this)` and want that class to stay only on that `li` not on any other until I click on any other

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I'm not sure if this is what you were asking for but hopefully it helps. Also make sure you have jQuery linked up.

You can store a key / value pair as follows:

localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
You can then retrieve the value as follows:

localStorage.getItem("key");
Remove:

localStorage.removeItem("key");
sessionStorage works the same as above but will only persist while the browser is open. It persists for the "session" of the browser. However localStorage will persist until it is removed by code or by clearing the browser.

Here's a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usja31hx/

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>


$( "li" ).click(function() {
  $( this).toggleClass('done')
});


.done{
    color: red;
}
```